# Selecting group of latest records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with abstract below

`Table_A`
`(RecordID int PK, LotID int, BatchID int, StatusID int, StatusTime datetime)`

Each lot identified by `LotID` can have multiple batches identified by `BatchID` and each batch's status is tracked.
Each time a status changes, a new record is inserted into `Table_A` indicating `LotID`, `BatchID`, `StatusID` and `StatusTime`.
I need to filter a single latest record for each batch. Could I do it with single `SELECT DISTINCT` statement or should I try to `JOIN` the table on itself, `ORDER BY` `StatusTime` and `SELECT TOP 1` record for each `LotID'+`BatchID` set ? How would you take a stab at it in T-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dataset with a `row_number()` column to order a subset of data:

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
      RecordID
    , LotID
    , BatchID
    , StatusID
    , StatusTime 
    , batchrank = ROW_NUMBER() 
                  OVER( PARTITION BY BatchId
                        ORDER BY StatusTime DESC )
  FROM Table_A
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE batchrank = 1
```

Comment: Works great! How is performance aspect of these functions on large tables? Any indexes suggested?